# Should we use all $N$ correspondence points to compute Homography or just $4$ points?

Tags: image-processing, self-study, homography

Given correspondences of $(x,x')$, we want to find a Homography matrix $H$ that maps $x' = Hx$. If we use 4 corresponding non - collinear points and the matrix $H$ has rank $n-1$, then the homogenous equation $Ah =0$ has a unique solution up to a constant. Suppose we find more than $4$ corresponding pairs of points, we get an overdetermined system of equation and we have to use least squares minimisation to find the solution.

I am curious as to whether it is better to just use $4$ points or $>4$ points to find the Homography ?

Also, it makes sense that from a linear algebra perspective, I am unable to solve the homogenous equation exactly when we have an overdetermined system. However, from a planar perspective, given my correspondence points are good, shouldn't there be an exact solution ?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally better to use all the points you have, since often, errors are independent per point.

> given my correspondence points are good, shouldn't there be an exact
> solution

Sure, but in realistic situations, it's not usually the case and/or you don't know that the points are good / which points are good.

A typical approach is to use all the points you have, but reject "bad" points using outlier-rejectiong  (e.g. [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) ) the [MIT 6.869 - Advances in Computer Vision - Lecture 13 - Homographies and RANSAC](http://6.869.csail.mit.edu/fa12/lectures/lecture13ransac/lecture13ransac.pdf) slides have an example of such a procedure.